# Is there a limit for the number of values can be present in 'IN' Operator in mysql?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I would like to know a couple of things regarding in operator in mysql.

1. The number of values in the in operator, Is there a limit?
2. Does it improve the performance if the values are sorted? Say employeeids. If the ids are given sorted in the criteria, Will it improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

1. Well, generally this number isn't directly limited, but you shouldn't exceed `max_allowed_packet` size with your query overall. SO basically there is a limit
2. As far as I know, if you don't sort it yourself, mysql will do it for you.

But in case of a really large `IN` query consider replacing it with `INNER JOIN` with temporary table, containing all values. It will be faster.